# Why won't the Xilinx block RAM in a Spartan-3E consistently return data in a single clock cycle?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, timing-analysis, spartan-3

I'm creating a design using Verilog on a Xilinx Spartan-3E (XC3S500E) that uses multiple dual-port block RAMs, all instantiated through Verilog primitives such as `RAMB16_S18_S18`. I am using one port for both reading and writing (using write-enable) and the second for only reading (by setting `WEB` to 0). Both ports share the same clock. The block RAM is set to 18-bit wide, but I am ignoring the parity data (that is, not using its output value, and always writing zeros to parity bits)

I am using Xilinx ISE 13.4 and synthesizing/implementing using the GUI workflow with default settings. (non-default settings such as aggressive timing optimization and/or physical synthesis did not have a difference in regard to this issue)

I have timing constraints made for my one and only clock net, and it is consistent with the actual clock signal being put in (the constraint is for 50MHz, there is a 50MHz clock on the dev board I am using, and the timing report states that the maximum frequency for my design is 64.7MHz. The clock runs through a clock mutliplexer used as a clock enable, before going to the entirety of my logic.

In my code, I have a state machine that has three states (transitioning on rising edge of the same 50MHz clock that the block RAM uses):

1. Write address to a register connected to the address inputs of ports A and B.
2. Read data, perform some logic operations on it, and write it to a `reg[15:0]` that is connected to DIA (data in A) on the block RAM (with the address not changing). Turn on write enable for port A.
3. Read some IO pins into unrelated registers. Turn off block RAM write enable.

This consistently succeeds in a behavioral simulation in ISim, and (although it had less testing than the simulator) consistently succeeds on port A. Port B has *identical* logic (simply bit-slicing for address, and the same configuration for SSR, SRVAL, INIT) but does not succeed in reading during this one clock cycle. By simply adding an extra state between 1 and 2 (thus giving a setup time of over one entire clock cycle for the address) the design works, although as a learner of FPGA development I would like to know why and how to avert it.

According to [Xilinx datasheet DS312](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds312.pdf) and timing diagrams within, this should be an acceptable way of using the block RAM. There are setup and hold times given in that same datasheet, but the ISE tools should already be aware of them and apply them during timing analysis, if I'm not mistaken. Additionally, I've re-read the block RAM section of UG331 (Spartan-3 Generation User Guide) a few times and could not find any inconsistencies between the instructions and my use of the block RAM.

The timing report list of the slowest paths mysteriously does not list any paths going to the offending RAM port.

If someone could make a recommendation, that would be appreciated, as I've spent quite a while debugging this and fear that I might be making some beginners' mistake. If any additional info is needed, please let me know so I can provide it.

Comment: BlockRAMs have a 2 cycle delay. They use synchronous write and read.

Comment: @Paebbels Can you show me where it says that in one of the datasheets? I might have missed it as I'm not 100% adept with FPGA technology and datasheet organization yet. Also, I was under the impression that according to the timing diagram on page 41 of the datasheet I linked, (and after some discussion on IRC) that the output would be available in two cycles if there was an extra synchronous register after the output, which there is not in my design.

Comment: @Paebbels Also UG331: "A read operation requires only one clock edge." I'm not sure if it's some sort of pipelining (they don't have *any* mention of it and it also isn't consistent with the identical timing diagrams as those in the datasheet DS312).

Comment: It used to be the case that you needed to explicitly set timing constraints between FFs and BlockRams as both start and endpoints. If you're getting next-cycle results (BlockRams are synchronous as Paebbels says, but in an unusual way) but inconsistently between PAR runs, look into this. If I can dig out a really old UCF file I'll post an answer.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'll look intothat. As I'm a beginner, it'll probably take me a bit of time to find and read the appropriate documentation; I am not very familiar with the semantics and syntax of timing constraints other than the ones governing the needed frequency for a clock and anything synchronous to it.

Comment: BlockRams are unusual in - as I understand it - pipelining the address (and write data), not the read data - hence "read operation requires one clock edge". You can present the address fairly late in a cycle (which is why I believe it's the address that's pipelined). In the next cycle you get the data ... after a substantial delay (again suggesting the data ISN'T pipelined) and in devices of that era, you need explicit constraints for timing analysis to account for that delay.

Comment: Keywords - Constraints Guide : cgd.pdf; TIMESPEC FROM BRAM TO FF (and vice versa). (From memory, BRAM may be the wrong word. UCF syntax is odd, inconsistent, sometimes case sensitive, and errors in it are poorly diagnosed if at all.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks. I'm currently looking through the constraint guide right now.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'm not sure exactly what I'm constraining here. I'm going from one block RAM to logic to another RAM's input address (through a register). Do I want a constraint from block RAM to block RAM, or do I need two separate constraints, one from a block RAM to a FF and the other from the FF to the next block RAM, such that the sum of their times is less than the period-(delay+setup)?

Comment: You probably need BRAM to BRAM. I vaguely recall setting FF to FF, BRAM to BRAM, FF to BRAM, BRAM to FF, all to the same as my clock period. That worked. Experiment with editing UCF and re-running timing analysis - hopefully you'll see new failures.

Comment: @BrianDrummond OK, thanks. I'll try it (although it might take a while, my ISE installation is running in a slow VM due to driver issues otherwise)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25783/discussion-between-hexafraction-and-brian-drummond).

Answer (score 1):

Newly written data at the rising-edge is available directly after this edge only at the same port. Actually, the data input is internally forwarded to the data output of the same RAM port. Also called `WRITE_FIRST` mode.

But, it is never forwarded to the output of the other RAM port, regardless of the specified `WRITE_MODE`. It will be available for reading (of course at a another rising edge) after the internal write to the memory has been completed. In your example it is just the next rising clock edge, because the internal write time is always smaller (faster) than the minimum allowed clock period.

This behavior is described in [XAPP 463 Using Block RAM in Spartan-3 Generation FPGAs](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp463.pdf#page=21) in section Dual-Port RAM Conflicts and Resolution. The given example there uses different clocks, but is also applies whe the same clock is used for both ports.

This behaviour is still the same in current FPGAs from Xilinx and Altera.

The forwarding to the other RAM port has to be done by your one with surrounding logic.

Comment: This is a fairly old question, so I'd need to look at the design again, but I don't believe the address in question was the same across the two ports.